# How to reuse Drawable in ListView item without causing memory leak in Android?

Tags: android, listview, memory-leaks

My listview item uses two Drawables. The asset is checked.png and another is unchecked.png. Depends on the status of the item, one of them will get used. In order to reduce space, I was thinking making them static inside listviewitem class.

`private static Drawable checked = getResources().getDrawable(checked_resourceId);` 
Then there will be just one checked drawable for all the listview items. However, it may cause memory leak since it is static. I'm wondering what should I do both save space and avoid memory leak. Or to be more general, how to cache things (like drawables or huge objects) to reduce memory usage while not causing memory leak because of references.

Comment: My general advice would be not not worry about "reducing space" in things like this unless you have measured it and determined that there is a problem you have to solve.

Comment: @BenP. I kinda agree. Don't optimize too early. Thanks. But if we do need to, do you have any advice?